# Azure B2C and Google gmail Accounts linked via OAuth – No Apparent Benefit

Tags: google-oauth, azure-ad-b2c

If you link an Azure B2C AD Tenant to Google+ there is no apparent benefit to the gmail end user or the application publisher.  The created Microsoft Account alias has its own password and does not really seem to be tied to the gmail account.  The prime OAuth benefit of using gmail as the username password source does really work that way in Azure B2C for gmail accounts.

I linked my Azure B2C tenant with Google+ as described here … ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-goog-app )

Is there something special I did not do such as activate an API on the Google+ side? 
Or is it all an illusion and Azure B2C does not let google gmail users actually use their real credentials like any other OAuth provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced article describes how to register Google as an identity provider for your Azure AD B2C tenant, but it is not yet enabled for users.

You must then create a sign-up or sign-in policy, as described at [Azure Active Directory B2C: Built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy), and **add Google as an identity provider for this policy**.

As result of this, the end user can choose to sign up or sign in using their Google identity, rather than sign up or sign in a local account with their Google email address.

Comment: ADAL v1.0  vs  MSAL v2.0    - The Policy and provider setup as described in those documents you linked to helped me pull it off.  The policies really expose all the ADAL v1.0 and MSAL v2.0 differences.   I had an ADAL v1.0 based solution and getting everything to work the B2C way under MSAL v2.0 was a very big deal.     There were several B2C improvements since September 2017, some documentations is not up to date.